# Voltage sequencing on power up

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-sequencing

I'm pretty new to PCB design, so my question may be obvious for some of you.
I am wiring the layout of an LCD screen on a PCB using KiCad. When I came to powering up, the [datasheet of the AT070TN92](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Retired/A13-LCD7-TS/resources/S700-AT070TN92.pdf) suggests applying DVDD voltage before AVDD. I know I can use voltage regulators to gain power. 
The question is, how can I ensure one voltage is applied before another? How can I make sure of the delay between DVDD and AVDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many regulators have an Enable pin. You can connect the output of DVDD's regulator to AVDD's Enable to ensure it powers up afterwards. The data sheet of the regulators will indicate at what voltage (at Enable) the regulator will turn on. You can use this info to time their power up. If the timing of their power up is not satisfactory using DVDD directly, you can modify the timing of the voltage at Enable using something like a voltage divider or a capacitor.

Comment: So you suggest using two different regulators ? For cost purpose i thought using only one reg. and then use capacitors/resistors to generate both AVDD and DVDD

Comment: I assume you mean using voltage dividers? I wouldn't suggest doing that. The first reason is the additional power. The second reason is your output voltage won't be regulated and will vary with how much current it's supplying (it will act as a supply with a high output impedance). If the current required was very low then a voltage divider might be adequate.

Comment: Yes i mean voltage dividers. The regulator have an output current going up to 1A, on the other hand the input pin of DVDD and AVDD requires only 185mA. So i was considering both current and voltage dividers. The current dividers will be placed just before entering the DVDD and AVDD pins

Comment: As an example, if you were hoping to generate a 10V rail using a voltage divider from a 16V rail, you might use a 1k and 600R resistor in your divider. This will end up looking like a 16V supply with a 375R output impedance. Meaning, as your load changes, the 10V rail will vary significantly.